# TypeError: setTimeout(...).unref is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am running my jest test suite in nodejs and getting below error

**node version - v14.17.4**

**mac bigSur**

**jest version - 26.6.3**

```
TypeError: setTimeout(...).unref is not a function
    at fail (/app/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/client.js:183:17)
    at /app/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/client.js:205:9
    at /app/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/client.js:350:9
    at callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:17)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Where is your test suit code?

Comment: It has many test suites and not sure exactly where is it coming from, but if we look at the error stack trace it looks like it is breaking in node-rdkafka.
Moreover setTimeout function is not being used anywhere in the codebase.

Comment: Hi, please check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59650031/7662325

Comment: This worked now that error is gone, but i still see one error where my test cases run but it does not terminate gracefully, but keeps on hanging there

Answer (score 0):

in your `jest.config.js`, make sure there's this:

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

See more about this option on the [testEnvironment docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string)